# when date change, after every midnight my software disable to login

Tags: node.js, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have create a software in angular12, nodejs and mysql for database. We host this on server IP address, but everyday after 12am midnight, when date change, it's disconnected from database. We are not able to login until we again restart node server.js file. After restart it's working fine. But everyday it's disconnect from server when date change. Please anyone help me to understand this issue and how to resolve it? I want to update it when I start server.js file, it will be never stop when date change.

this is my connection.js file

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
require('dotenv').config();

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log("Connected");
    }
    else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});


module.exports = connection;
```

2. this is my server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./index');

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

3. this is index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
let cors = require ('cors');
const connection = require('./connection');
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');
const stockRoute = require('./routes/stock');
const allocationRoute = require('./routes/allocation');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/user',userRoute);
app.use('/stock',stockRoute);
app.use('/allocation',allocationRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

can anyone guide me how to make server continuously start when date change than also?